# Porcentagem em Procedure SQL

Tags: sql, procedure, porcentagem

Bom dia pessoal,
Preciso criar uma regra dentro de uma procedure, onde primeiramente preciso pegar 100% dos ids marcados com AP.
E então destes 100%, preciso pegar 15% dos ids status = 10.

Porém não sei como fazer para "empilhar esses ids." Alguém teria alguma dica?

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM dg.Registros  
            WHERE tipo = 'ap' and idregistro = @idregistro
           )
                            
    
                
--Regra - 15% dos registros
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM dg.Registros
            WHERE idregistro = @idregistro
            AND idregistro IN (
            SELECT t.total * 15/100 as perc FROM dg.Registros q,
                ( 
                  SELECT count(idregistro) as total FROM dg.Registros
                  WHERE  tipo = 'ap'
                  AND idregistroStatus = 10
                  AND idregistro = @idregistro
                ) t
                  GROUP BY total
            )
            )
```

Comment: Não entendi sua explicação do que é para fazer e nem a sua lógica mas, provavelmente, a cláusula HAVING te ajude. Certamente este `IN` está sendo usado de modo indevido.

Comment: Procedures são escritas em linguagens específicas dos respectivos SGBD , informe o SGBD , versão etc.

Comment: Bom dia, já consegui resolver. SQL versão 2017. Obrigada pelo retorno.